# sftp issues using pysftp

Tags: python, sftp

I'm trying to send a file from local machine to server thru sftp using pysftp

When I login to the server using command line as:

```
sftp -o port=111 user_name@host
```

then do `pwd` I get the `/` as the current location

So I want to do the same in `pysftp` as:

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

with pysftp.Connection("host", username="user_name", password="password", port=111, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
    print(sftp.pwd)
    sftp.put(local_file, sftp.pwd)
```

but I get the error `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied`

Although, I'm able to sftp using the same credentials in command line and an ftp client like FileZilla

Here the full error trace:

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/workspace/segments-upload/media_math_segments_upload.py", line 232, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if main() else 1)
  File "C:/workspace/segments-upload/media_math_segments_upload.py", line 226, in main
    process(s3_bucket, s3_dir, sftp_host, sftp_path, sftp_user_name, sftp_password, sftp_port)
  File "C:/workspace/segments-upload/media_math_segments_upload.py", line 182, in process
    sftp_file(local_file, sftp_host, sftp_path, sftp_user_name, sftp_password, sftp_port)
  File "C:/workspace/segments-upload/media_math_segments_upload.py", line 105, in sftp_file
    sftp.put(local_file, sftp.pwd)
  File "C:\Users\tkaghdo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 364, in put
    confirm=confirm)
  File "C:\Users\tkaghdo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 676, in put
    return self.putfo(fl, remotepath, file_size, callback, confirm)
  File "C:\Users\tkaghdo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 634, in putfo
    with self.file(remotepath, 'wb') as fr:
  File "C:\Users\tkaghdo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 327, in open
    t, msg = self._request(CMD_OPEN, filename, imode, attrblock)
  File "C:\Users\tkaghdo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 730, in _request
    return self._read_response(num)
  File "C:\Users\tkaghdo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 781, in _read_response
    self._convert_status(msg)
  File "C:\Users\tkaghdo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 809, in _convert_status
    raise IOError(errno.EACCES, text)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Comment: A full stack trace would be helpful. Knowing that it's an IOError doesn't really help in knowing *which* operation failed, and whether it's a remote exception being locally represented or a local syscall failing.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by providing the name of the file on the remote server. So I just changed

```
sftp.put(local_file, sftp.pwd)
```

to

```
sftp.put(local_file, "file_name.dat")
```